# Portal 2 glitchy fonts

Tags: technical-issues, portal-2

Is it just me or the fonts are looking somewhat glitchy for some reason?

For example: In the following screenshot, the letters especially `i` and captial `S` and `M` doesn't appear to be smooth.

[image]

In the subtitles, the letters `g` and `c` are appearing odd with an extra spacing.

[image]

On the other hand, the game runs smooth at 60 fps and in game textures are just fine. I have tried to change various video settings and screen resolutions with no luck. So, I am guessing is this graphics card dependent or is there something else I might need to change?

Comment: Your screenshot shows only 2x MSAA. Have you tried turning it up to 8x?

Comment: Yes, with no changes at all.

Comment: Can we get some details about your computer like OS and hardware? Also your native monitor resolution please

Comment: Yes, It's a laptop with 1366x768 on a Windows 8.1 OS, 8 GB RAM, i5 2.6 Ghz processor, with switchable graphics Intel HD 4000/AMD 7000 Series. It's pretty weird how only 2 or 3 letters are looking odd enough while the others appear to be just fine.

Comment: I have a feeling it's to do with the weird resolution, have you got another (16:9 or 4:3) screen you could test it on?

Comment: I mostly use the native resolution in all the games but switching between the resolutions like 1280x768 doesn't make any change.

Comment: Is your game completely up to date?

Comment: I downloaded the game from steam just today, so I guess it must be since auto-updates are enabled.

Comment: Try verifying your game cache: Right click on Portal 2 in your library, click properties, then go to local files -> Verify integrity of game cache. Once it's done, see if the problem has been resolved

Comment: It's done but nothing. Perhaps, it's something else.

Comment: It looks as though [my suspicions were correct](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2308219), although I have been unable to find a solution. Other than that, I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It appears to be some font related bug as I just  found some people were also having other issues related to with fonts not appearing or appearing too large and wide etc.

Comment: try 1. setting the launch options in steam and adding: `-w 1366 -h 768` or 2. Changing your laptops resolution to a different resolution like 1280x720 (and removing the launch options from 1.)

Comment: It doesn't help with 1366x768 but if I change the in-game resolution to 1280x720, it makes the subtitle text letters a lot smoother and also fixes the glitching of `g` and `c` letters. So, perhaps, the 1366x768 resolution doesn't fit well as it seems.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QB1iT.jpg) at 1280x720 under full screen.

Comment: Looks like a resizing problem. Try changing the fullscreen optimizations in your OS, or graphical settings in the device driver software of your graphics card (Catalyst / nVidia Control Panel).

Comment: @Joachim: Which settings? Catalyst control never worked on my laptop.